# To split a json file.. Extracting data between curly braces

Tags: regex, json, sed, awk, grep

I have a json file. I want to split that file into different parts..

Following is my file's content.
I want to split the content based on the curly brackets {},

```
"1010320": {
    "abc": [
        "1012220", 
        "hiiiiiiiii."
    ], 
    "xyz": "Describe"
}, 
"1012757": {
    "pqr": [
        "1013757", 
        "x"
    ]
}, 
"1014220": {
    "abc": [
        "1018420", 
        "sooooo"
    ], 
    "answer": "4th"
}, 
"1019660": {
    "abc": [
        "1031920", 
        "welcome"
    ], 
    "xyz": "Describing&Interpreting"
}, 
"1034280": {
    "abc": [
        "1040560", 
        "Ok..."
    ], 
    "nop": "Student Question"
},
```

The output should be:

```
1)     "abc": [
            "1012220", 
            "hiiiiiiiii."
        ], 
        "xyz": "Describe"


2)         "pqr": [
            "1013757", 
            "x"
        ]


3)         "abc": [
            "1018420", 
            "sooooo"
        ], 
        "answer": "4th"
```

plz.. help..

Comment: recommend to use the exist tools, such as jq, jsawk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will be useful for you

```
(?<=\{)\n\s+((?:[\n]+|.*)+?)\n\}
```

regex demo here  : http://regex101.com/r/rS3wI5

Comment: Why use Regex when a JSON parser will suffice?

Comment: It is giving an error... syntax error near unexpected token `\n\s+((?:[\n]+|.*)+?)\n\}'

Comment: how are you using this regex btw ?